# How to use "Lest"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

How to properly use "lest" in a sentence?

The Indian batsmen took blows on their bodies but did not make a fuss about the surface. **Lest the match was called off, they brushed aside fears over the pitch.**

Comment: was -> be, but also there's more needed to the context to make the whole thing work.

Comment: You just *did* use it in a sentence. What do you find confusing about it?

Comment: 'Lest' isn't used much nowadays, and fronting the _lest_-clause makes it sound even more archaic. In olden days, the subjunctive (or is it really a subjunctive usage?) would have been used: They brushed aside fears over the pitch, lest the match be called off'

Answer (score -2):

Lest implies 'so that not' 
In a sentence, "Work hard, lest you should miss the chance" means, "Work hard, so that you should not miss the chance".
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lest

Some teachers teach the use of lest as 'if not'or 'unless'. Let us see the following:

Work hard, lest you should fail.
Work hard, so that you should not fail.
Work hard, if not you will fail
Unless you work hard, you will fail. (Structured altered)
If you do not work hard, you will fail.

Please edit it,if I am wrong.